# I2S to PDM Conversion

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, audio-codec

We are looking to use the [TLV320AIC3111](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv320aic3111.pdf) audio codec to process some sound data that we are receiving from [MP34DT05-A microphone](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/mp34dt05-a.pdf). We then look to transmit the data wirelessly over BLE using the [BlueNRG-1](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bluenrg-1.pdf) BLE Module. We've already worked on the BlueNRG-1 and have managed to transmit PDM data input over BLE. But the TLV320AIC3111 supports only *I2S, Left-Justified, Right-Justified, DSP, and TDM Audio Interfaces* according to the datasheet given above.

I'd like to know if anyone knows of any way to convert I2S to PDM, or maybe a similar BLE module that supports I2S input. We'd prefer the first option though as we've already got the BLE figured out.

Comment: According to the data-sheet, the TLV320AIC3111 has an I2C bus, and so does the BlueNRG-1, isn't that enough?

Comment: I2C is not an audio bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t seem like there’s a way to use a PDM mic with that TI audio codec. Analog would work though.

Likewise, the BlueNRG expects PDM, but the TI codec only makes PCM (I2S). So the TI part seems to be a poor fit either way.

The Cypress (formerly Broadcom) BLE solutions seem to support I2S.